# Mod-Rewrite rules are breaking 404 routing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am using the following `mod-rewrite` in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^$ pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

The intention is to hide the subdirectory called `/pages/` from displaying in the URL.

So this:  `http://mysite.com/pages/home.html`

Will look like this:  `http://mysite.com/home.html`

It works but there are some unintended consequences.

As a direct result of the `.htaccess` code I posted above, my 404 routing is no longer working at all.  Anything that should trigger a 404 error page is instead generating a `500 Server Error`.

How to fix?

---

**EDIT:**

As implied above, it does not matter if a custom 404 page is defined in the `.htaccess` or not.  Without it, or a bad path to the error page, the server should still route to its default 404 page, and not give a `500 Server Error`.

**Surely, there must be a standard way to suppress sections of a URL without breaking the normal routing of 404 errors.**  From my online research it seems that my method above commonly breaks the 404 routing, and yet so far, I've seen no applicable solution.   (This is not a Wordpress installation; just static HTML content)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Since I'm only wanting to suppress the one directory from the URL, I never mentioned that I also have other files & directories which are siblings to `/pages/` that cannot be pointed at `/pages/`, such as `/graphics/`, `/includes/`, `/css/`, `/cgi-bin/`, `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, etc.

Maybe this is all an exercise in futility or more trouble than it's worth?

Looking for a definitive answer either way.

Comment: Wy don't you just move the contents of /pages/ to / ?

Comment: Thanks @max_, of course I've considered that.  The answer is:  Because I'd like to keep my system logically organized with my static content all in one location.  If there really is no working solution, having `/pages/` visible within the URL isn't the worst thing in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following config will look for your static pages inside the `pages/` and if found, it'll display them. This shouldn't break 404.
Put it in root folder of your web in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1
```

Comment: Yes, very close!  It works for `/subdirectory/anyPage.html`, but it fails with a `404` on `/subdirectory/`, where it would normally be defaulting to `/subdirectory/index.html`.

Comment: You beat me to my own answer by a few seconds... so you earned the check-mark.

Comment: @KamilŠrot Don't know how I missed this but you saved me from a sleepless night. Took me at least 2 hours to figure out that I should simply check if the file exists in the destination folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are trying to do.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you to @Kamil Šrot for getting the closest working solution.  However, I needed to add another test ( `-d` ) to see if the requesting URI is a directory.

This is working great and the `404 error` page is again routing properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1
```

Answer (score -1):

How about adding an error page direction to your `htaccess` file to handle the 404 page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your/404.html
```

Comment: I already have that.  It does not matter if it's there or not.  Even when that line is deleted, the server gives a 500 instead of its default 404.